# Custom subtext in Woocommerce add to cart button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I like to add subtext to my default text add to cart button currently it's showing only buy it now!

I would like to have something like this:

[image: add-to-cart-button]

And if it possible for the checkout button as well but not the same text something different.

Comment: You could use a plugin [link]https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-custom-add-to-cart-labels/ or use a function [link]https://www.isitwp.com/change-default-add-to-cart-button-text-in-woocommerce/

Comment: I want to add subtext not the main "limited time special offer!" is the subtext.

Answer (score 0):

To change the add to cart text, and add the subtitle to the button, the following code will help you.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'woo_custom_cart_button_link', 10, 2);
function woo_custom_cart_button_link($button_text, $product) {
    return sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        'Add to Cart <br>Limited Period Offer'
    );
}
```